# Super Products Attributes Configuration - Double Price Uptick

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, stores

I'm creating a listing for coveralls in Magento with inseam and chest.  All inseam 32s have a price uptick in Super Products Attributes Configuration.  Also chest sizes 52 and 54 in Super Products Attributes Configuration carry a price uptick.  When on the Super Products Attributes Configuration I've filled out the table with these price upticks however in the case of inseam 32, chest 52 and inseam 32, chest 54 there are two price upticks when there should only be 1 - how can I change this?